# JS Check if Browser Supports CSS Snap Points

Tags: jquery, css, scroll-snap-points

Is there a simple way to check if a browser supports CSS Snap Points. I've set up a fail safe for a horizontal gallery but I'd like to turn off all the Javascript if the browser already natively supports snap points.

Also, are there any decent polyfills that might do a better job of what I've built here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking `document.body` `style` for `"scroll-snap-type"` property

```
  if ("scroll-snap-type" in document.body.style) {
    // do stuff with `scroll-snap-points`
  } else {
    // `scroll-snap-points` not supported
  }
```